# How come I can't have several hashmaps as member variable in my Custom object

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to have a firestore Document with several hashmaps as data objects on the server-side.

On the client-side (Android) I am using a POJO as a custom object to store and organize all data requested from firestore. This POJO implements Parcelable to be able to pass it through intent from an activity to another.

My POJO looks like this:

```
public class Session implements Parcelable {
    private Map<String, Boolean> firstHashmap;
    private Map<String, Boolean> secondHashmap;
    private Map<String, String> thirdHashmap;
    // constructors (first I notice that I can only create 1 constructor for a hashmap as a parameter, I wonder why)
    // getters and setters  

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    // Write the object's data to the passed-in Parcel
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {

    if (firstHashmap != null) {
        Bundle firstBundle = new Bundle();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : firstHashmap.entrySet()) {
            firstBundle.putBoolean(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        out.writeBundle(firstBundle);
    }

    // same thing for secondHashmap
    // same thing for thirdHashmap  

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Session> CREATOR = new 
            Parcelable.Creator<Session>() {
        public Session createFromParcel(Parcel in){
            return new Session(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Session[] newArray(int size) {
             return new Session[size];
        }
     };  

    // Constructor that takes a Parcel and gives you an object populated with it's values
    private Session(Parcel in) {

        Bundle firstBundle = new Bundle();
        firstBundle = in.readBundle(getClass().getClassLoader());
        Map<String, Boolean> tempFirstHashmap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String key: firstBundle.keySet()){
            tempFirstHashmap.put(key, firstBundle.getBoolean(key));
        }
        firstHashmap = firstBundle;

        // same thing for secondHashmap
        // same thing for thirdHashmap 
    }
}
```

It worked fine while I was having the same value data type in my hashmap i.e. Boolean but then I introduced thirdHashmap with String and everything went wrong: for instance when firstHashmap is null on the firestore document and thirdHashmap is not, I'm having Strings deserialized to my firstHashmap causing RuntimeError.

To sum up I am having some issue to get data from firestore and put them in the right place. If anyone could give me a clue it would be much appreciated :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please add the entire error, the code you are using to get the data and your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

To save you a lot of time and effort you can use a plugin to generate parceling code for you inside your POJO if you're using android studio just go to File>settings>plugins and there search for plugins and install it.
then go to your POJO and clear it from everything except your member variable(HashMap variables) after that just by right clicking your mouse on inside your class file and from your opened window click on generate you will find a new tab added to the last of the window called Parcelable click on it and choose what member variables you want to parcel. 
Note: If i were in your shoes i would delete all my firestore data on server-side and on client-side when a new change made to my POJO specially when I delete or change member variable, I hope this answer help you.